# NSJSONSerialization Not Parsing JSON Data From PHP File's SQL Query

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch, nsjsonserialization

So I'm trying to make a companion app for a Wordpress site for a friend. I have created a PHP file that queries the wp_posts table of the MySQL database

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts ORDER BY post_date_gmt DESC
```

I have run a cURL command on it and the output iis as expected (the table data in JSON format), so that is not the problem.

I think I've narrowed it down to the class I'm using that gets and populates the data. Here's the class:

```
#import "KYAPIQueryResultsHandler.h"
#import "KYAPIQueryResults.h"


@interface KYAPIQueryResultsProtocol()  {
NSMutableData * _downloadedData;
}
@end

@implementation KYAPIQueryResultsProtocol

-(void)downloadItems    {

    // Download the data via JSON format from API call
    NSURL *JSONFileURL = [NSURL             
URLWithString:@"http://jeffstockdale.com/API/pntjx_get_posts.php"];

// Create the request to the API
//    NSURLRequest *URLRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:JSONFileURL];
NSURLRequest *URLRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:JSONFileURL];

// Create the NSURL connection
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:URLRequest delegate:self];
}

#pragma mark NSURLConnectionDataProtocol Methods

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response        
{
// Initialize the data object
_downloadedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data   {
[_downloadedData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

// Create an array to store the locations
NSMutableArray *_Posts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Parse JSON data that came in
NSError *error;
NSArray *JSONArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_downloadedData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

// Loop through JSON objects, create question objects and add them to the questions array
for (int i = 0; i < [JSONArray count]; i++)   {

    NSDictionary *JSONElement = JSONArray[i];

    // Create a new location object and set its props to the JSONElement properties
    KYAPIQueryResults *newResult = [[KYAPIQueryResults alloc] init];

    [newResult setID:JSONElement[@"ID"]];
    [newResult setPost_author:JSONElement[@"post_author"]];
    [newResult setComment_count:JSONElement[@"comment_count"]];
    [newResult setComment_status:JSONElement[@"comment_status"]];
    [newResult setGuid:JSONElement[@"guid"]];
    [newResult setMenu_order:JSONElement[@"menu_order"]];
    [newResult setPing_status:JSONElement[@"ping_status"]];
    [newResult setPinged:JSONElement[@"pinged"]];
    [newResult setPost_author:JSONElement[@"post_author"]];
    [newResult setPost_content:JSONElement[@"post_content"]];
    [newResult setPost_content_filtered:JSONElement[@"post_content_filtered"]];
    [newResult setPost_date:JSONElement[@"post_date"]];
    [newResult setPost_date_gmt:JSONElement[@"post_date_gmt"]];
    [newResult setPost_excerpt:JSONElement[@"post_excerpt"]];
    [newResult setPost_mime_type:JSONElement[@"post_mime_type"]];
    [newResult setPost_modified:JSONElement[@"post_modified"]];
    [newResult setPost_modified_gmt:JSONElement[@"post_modified_gmt"]];
    [newResult setPost_name:JSONElement[@"post_name"]];
    [newResult setPost_parent:JSONElement[@"post_parent"]];
    [newResult setPost_password:JSONElement[@"post_password"]];
    [newResult setPost_status:JSONElement[@"post_status"]];
    [newResult setPost_title:JSONElement[@"post_title"]];
    [newResult setPost_type:JSONElement[@"post_type"]];
    [newResult setTo_ping:JSONElement[@"to_ping"]];

    // Add this question to the locations array
    [_Posts addObject:newResult];

    // Notify delegate that the class is ready to pass back items
    if ([self delegate])    {
        [[self delegate] itemsDownloaded:_Posts];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

I'm really scratching my head on this one. I've tried putting a NSLog expression to make sure the data is downloading, and it is. Thank you in advance for any help you could offer!

Comment: Can you add an NSLog statement that prints the JSONArray and the error?

Comment: You probably shouldn't call the itemsDownloaded method every time an item is added to the array, just at the very end when _Posts is complete. By the way, leading underscore like in _Posts should be used for instance variables only. All of this has nothing to do with your problem, but you might want to change that anyway.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what the problem is?

Comment: When I've added an NSLog to print the contents of the array I get a ton of "null"s.  And thank you for the advice for calling itemsDownloaded.  I was trying to make it a method however that I could call when I make an object from the class.  Do you believe I was doing it wrong? Please advise.

Comment: Printing the error (which I didn't think to do because there weren't any halts) shows the following:

    2014-10-07 15:31:54.016 ThePoint[30251:1379096] Error    Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Garbage at end.) UserInfo=0x7ff925c39980 {NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}.  I'm going to write a custom response (not calculated) and see if it works to confirm that is is because of the warning at the end.

Comment: @pbasdf it seems that the problem is in the Warning at the end of the PHP.  Do you happen to have any suggestions on how to get rid of that Warning?

Answer (score 0):

Just checking it now, the requested URL does not return valid JSON. Here's the bit at the end that invalidates it:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in    <b>/home/content/83/6031183/html/API/pntjx_get_posts.php</b> on line <b>49</b><br />
```

If you log the `NSError` passed into `NSJSONSerialization`, it should say much the same.

Comment: As an aside, there are a number of troubling patterns in your code, from unconventional variable and method naming, to incorrect usage of the networking APIs. As someone just starting out, you might want to consider a framework like AFNetworking, which abstracts away much of the boilerplate necessary to send and receive information.

Comment: Thank you.  Do you have any recommendations for places to get started with AFNetworking?  Also, what recommendations would you have for handling that warning?

Comment: Okay, I've "fixed" the error at the end.  I've switched from using my own PHP back end to using the RESful JSON API WordPress plugin.  The new link I'm using is http://jeffstockdale.com/api/get_recent_posts.php .  Now I'm getting a compiler error.  I'm going to try to redo the properties of KYAPIQueryResults and see where that gets me.  Please stand by.